# Plotting relationships among variables - Python

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I'm trying to create a pairwise scatter plots among the variables of the classic `titanic` data, specifically the `train.csv`. This is the code:

```
#scatterplot
sns.set()
sns.pairplot(df, dropna=True)
plt.show()
```

But it shows me the following error:

```
ValueError: max must be larger than min in range parameter.
```

Comment: You forgot to provide the data that is used to produce this error. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You likely have NaNs in your dataframe.  This is the error you'll see when trying to create scatter plots and histograms with arrays containing NaNs.

Comment: Matplotlib can handle NaNs very well. Not sure what "null-values" are though.

Comment: I mean NaNs when I say nulls, I guess maybe that wasn't clear to you.  Regardless of your opinion on how well matplotlib may or may not handle NaNs when trying to create scatter plots and histograms, I believe my answer is correct.  Also, I do think that OP's error message is pretty misleading if my answer is indeed correct, which in this case supports the view that NaNs could be handled more gracefully by matplotlib.

Comment: It doesn't work even if I drop the NaNs. Why could it be?

Comment: @Evan There is no problem with scatterplots. For histograms there may be problems, because mathematically a histogram containing nans is ill-defined. While numpy does not compute a histogram with nans, matplotlib at least works around this. If you find a problem where nans are not supported by matplotlib, feel free to open an issue at [the matplolib issue tracker](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues).